# Angular - drag and drop - component is not rendering before drag start

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, drag-and-drop, angular-dragdrop

I am using angular drag and drop @angular/cdk/drag-drop.

Here is a stackblitz that describes the problem:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/cdk-drag-drop-index-bug-kqspbh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

I want the dragText to change while i am dragging the item component.
It is changing the item dragText but its not re-rendering the component after the text change.
What am I doing wrong?

I tried changing the text on mousedown event, but its a good solution.

Comment: Please post what have you done in ondrag change event and post your code of implementation

Comment: @Ashish I just change the dragText. It is updating in the html only after the item is dropped.

Comment: You need to make sure of updating the list and store where it fetch from.

Comment: As you can see, the list of items is a public list, and it should re render when i change an item.